# Error in QuickOSM panel. I'm unable to access OSM data

Tags: qgis, python, quickosm

[image]
I've installed QuickOSM plugin and tried to import osm data but it's showing error like this... being a beginner it's been a headache for the last few days... I'm unable to work... Searching so many sources to resolve this but couldn't find the correct way.

#### What is the bug?

```
2023-11-24T23:36:13     INFO    The OSM file is: C:\Users\ACER\Downloads\map.osm
2023-11-24T23:36:14     CRITICAL    A critical error occurred, this is the traceback:
2023-11-24T23:36:14     CRITICAL    
2023-11-24T23:36:14     CRITICAL    base_processing_panel.py
2023-11-24T23:36:14     CRITICAL    Error: Algorithm qgis:checkvalidity not found
             
2023-11-24T23:36:14     CRITICAL     File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\base_processing_panel.py", line 47, in run
              self._run()
             
              File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\osm_file_panel.py", line 223, in _run
              open_file(
             
              File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\process.py", line 106, in open_file
              layers = osm_parser.processing_parse()
             
              File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\parser\osm_parser.py", line 133, in processing_parse
              validity = processing.run(
             
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 108, in run
              return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
             
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 169, in runAlgorithm
              raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
             
2023-11-24T23:36:28     INFO    The OSM file is: C:\Users\ACER\Downloads\map.osm
2023-11-24T23:36:28     CRITICAL    A critical error occurred, this is the traceback:
2023-11-24T23:36:28     CRITICAL    
2023-11-24T23:36:28     CRITICAL    base_processing_panel.py
2023-11-24T23:36:28     CRITICAL    Error: Algorithm qgis:checkvalidity not found
             
2023-11-24T23:36:28     CRITICAL     File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\base_processing_panel.py", line 47, in run
              self._run()
             
              File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\osm_file_panel.py", line 223, in _run
              open_file(
             
              File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\process.py", line 106, in open_file
              layers = osm_parser.processing_parse()
             
              File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\parser\osm_parser.py", line 133, in processing_parse
              validity = processing.run(
             
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 108, in run
              return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
             
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 169, in runAlgorithm
              raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
```

#### Environment

- QuickOSM version: 3.32.1
- QGIS version:3.32.1
- OS: windows 11

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What versions of QGIS and the plug-in are you using?  What are the precise and detailed steps you use to install and test your installation?

Comment: Please always present error messages as formatted text rather than only in a picture.

Comment: No 3.32.1 version of  the plugin. The latest version of QuickOSM is 2.2.3.

Comment: Hi, this is not the first time i read about this error. For some reason, your Processing core plugin was deactivated and QuickOSM doesn't have access to the Check Validity tool. You can activate (tick on) the Processing plugin from the Installed tab of Plugins Manager window, to solve the error right now. But it is recommended to start a new user profile from qgis settings menu, and install QuickOSM in that profile. I think a Qgis update broke previous installed plugins and Processing one had a kind of panic and deactivated itself.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca, now that the question has been re-opened it is probably worth adding your comment as an answer. It seems to be a valid solution.

Comment: Could you please add a proper screenshot, not a photo?

Answer (score 3):

> 2023-11-24T23:36:28     CRITICAL    Error: Algorithm qgis:checkvalidity not found

This error means that you do not have access to the Processing tools (in this case, QuickOSM needs to use the Check Validity tool and can't find it).

**The Processing tools can be activated from the Plugins Manager window, in the Installed plugins tab.**

Make sure the Processing plugin is activated (checked). If it is not, like in the figure below, simply check it.

[image: Plugins Manager window]

---

I'm not sure what could be causing this core plugin to deactivate itself, but it is likely that a QGIS update turned out to be incompatible with one of the installed plugins and after having raised an exception, the Processing tools have been deactivated.

The best practice to avoid suffering from this problem is to always create a new user profile, from the Settings menu, to be used with each new version of QGIS that is installed. And in the new user profile, reinstall the plugins that you are going to use in that version of QGIS.

Comment: Thank you so much.... Problem resolved...❤️